# Parsing JSON datetime?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am consuming a JSON API that returns datetime values as a string in the following format:

> /Date(1370651105153)/

How can I parse a value like this into a datetime variable in rails?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That appears to be a UNIX timestamp (seconds since epoch). Additionally it appears to be milliseconds since epoch.

So you can convert it like so - given that `value` is a String that looks like:

```
value = "/Date(1370651105153)/"

if value =~ /\/Date\((\d+)\)\//
  timestamp = $1.to_i
  time = Time.at(timestamp / 1000)
  # time is now a Time object
end
```

You need to divide by 1000 since `Time#at` expects its argument to be seconds and not milliseconds since the epoch.

Answer (score 4):

There are a few errors in andyisnowskynet's answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/25817039/5633460): There's a minor RegEx error which means it won't detect positive timezones; and it won't support [timezones that aren't aligned to full hours](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/time-zones-interesting.html) such as `-0430` ([VET](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/vet)). Also, the `Time` object it returns *could* be honouring proper Ruby timezone handling instead of adding a time offset, which would be the more-conventional way to do this.

This is my improved version of that answer...

First, for datetime values expressed in this format, the time serial part (e.g. `1370651105153` in OP's example) is ALWAYS the number of milliseconds since `1970-01-01 00:00:00 GMT`, and that is not influenced by the presence or absence of a timezone suffix. Hence, any timezone included as part of the string does not **change** the point in history that this represents. It only serves to state which timezone the "observer" was in *at the time*.

Ruby `Time` objects are able to handle these two pieces of information (i.e. the actual datetime "value" and the timezone "metadata"). To demonstrate:

```rb
a = Time.at(-1).utc
# => 1969-12-31 23:59:59 UTC
b = Time.at(-1).getlocal('+09:30')
# => 1970-01-01 09:29:59 +0930
a == b
# => true
```

As you can see, even though both look like different values (owing to their different timezones in which they are expressed), the `==` equality operator shows they actually reference the same *moment in time*.

Knowing this, we could improve on `parse_json_datetime` as follows (correcting the other errors too):

```rb
def parse_json_datetime(datetime)
  # "/Date(-62135575200000-0600)/" seems to be the default date returned
  # if the value is null:
  if datetime == "/Date(-62135575200000-0600)/"
    # Return nil because it is probably a null date that is defaulting to 0.
    # To be more technically correct you could just return 0 here if you wanted:
    return nil
  elsif datetime =~ %r{/Date\(([-+]?\d+)([-+]\d+)?\)/}
    # We've now parsed the string into:
    # - $1: Number of milliseconds since the 1/1/1970 epoch.
    # - $2: [Optional] timezone offset.
    # Divide $1 by 1000 because it is in milliseconds and Time uses seconds:
    seconds_since_epoch = $1.to_i / 1000.0
    time = Time.at(seconds_since_epoch.to_i).utc 
    # We now have the exact moment in history that this represents,
    # stored as a UTC-based "Time" object.

    if $2
      # We have a timezone, so convert its format (adding a colon)...
      timezone = $2.gsub(/(...)(..)/, '\1:\2')
      # ...then apply it to the Time object:
      time = time.getlocal(timezone)
    end
    time
  else
    raise "Unrecognized date format."
  end
end
```

Then we can test:

```rb
# See: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/asp-net-json-date/
parse_json_datetime("/Date(1198908717056-0700)/")
# => 2007-12-28 23:11:57 -0700

# 1 minute before the epoch, but in ACST:
parse_json_datetime("/Date(-60000+0930)/")
# => 1970-01-01 09:29:00 +0930

# Same as above, but converted naturally to its UTC equivalent:
parse_json_datetime("/Date(-60000+0930)/").utc
# => 1969-12-31 23:59:00 UTC

# Same as above, with timezone unspecified (implying UTC):
parse_json_datetime("/Date(-60000)/")
# => 1969-12-31 23:59:00 UTC

# OP's example:
parse_json_datetime("/Date(1370651105153)/")
# => 2013-06-08 00:25:05 UTC

# Same as above, but stated in two different timezones:
aaa = parse_json_datetime("/Date(1370651105153-0200)/")
# => 2013-06-07 22:25:05 -0200
bbb = parse_json_datetime("/Date(1370651105153-0800)/")
# => 2013-06-07 16:25:05 -0800

# As "rendered" strings they're not the same:
aaa.to_s == bbb.to_s
# => false
# But as moments in time, they are equivalent:
aaa == bbb
# => true
# And, for the sake of the argument, if they're both expressed in the
# same timezone (arbitrary '-04:00' in this case) then they also render
# as equal strings:
aaa.getlocal('-04:00').to_s == bbb.getlocal('-04:00').to_s
```

Answer (score 1):

The integer seems to be a unixtime (in milliseconds). Just cut the last three digits off and feed the rest to `Time.at`:

```
Time.at(1370651105) # => 2013-06-08 04:25:05 +0400
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who needed a bit more robust solution that included a timezone, this is the parser I came up with:

```
def parse_json_datetime(datetime)
  # "/Date(-62135575200000-0600)/" seems to be the default date returned if the value is null
  if datetime == "/Date(-62135575200000-0600)/"
    # return nil because it is probably a null date that is defaulting to 0.
    # to be more technically correct you could just return 0 here if you wanted.
    return nil
  elsif datetime =~ /\/Date\(([-+]?\d+)(-+\d+)?\)\// # parse the seconds and timezone (if present)
    milliseconds_since_epoch = $1
    time = Time.at(milliseconds_since_epoch.to_i/1000.0).utc # divide by 1000 because it is in milliseconds and Time uses seconds

    if timezone_hourly_offset = $2
      timezone_hourly_offset = timezone_hourly_offset.gsub("0","").to_i
      time = time+(timezone_hourly_offset*60*60) # convert hourly timezone offset into seconds and add onto time
    end
    time
  else
    raise "Unrecognized date format."
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

[Active Support makes it easy to do this](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/JSON.html):

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'active_support/json'
require 'active_support/time'

Time.zone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'
ActiveSupport.parse_json_times = true

puts ActiveSupport::JSON.decode('{"hi":"2009-08-10T19:01:02Z"}')
```

Which will output:

```
{"hi"=>Mon, 10 Aug 2009 15:01:02 EDT -04:00}
```

Once you turn the `ActiveSupport.parse_json_times` flag on, then any JSON payload you decode will get any times automatically convered into `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone` objects.

Active Support [uses a regex to detect times](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/json/decoding.rb#L14). You can [read the tests](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/test/json/decoding_test.rb) to get a good idea of the time formats that it supports. Looks like it supports ISO 8601, but does *not* support Unix/POSIX/Epoch timestamps.

I was informed of this feature in Active Support when I created [this issue against Rails](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/32424).