# How to parse /Date(-62135578800000-0500)/ in Ruby/Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, time

I have the following date format which I need to parse in Ruby on Rails

```
/Date(-62135578800000-0500)/
```

This is 11/20/2016 1:16PM
I understand that the first part is in milliseconds and rest is timezone but I am still not able to parse it

Comment: Is that a string that happens to have slashes at both ends, or is it a regular expression?

Comment: Do you know which (approximate) date it should be?

Comment: @moveson I believe that it is a unix timestamp. The "/" are part of the date string and not a regular expression

Comment: @EricDuminil I'm not sure what date this is supposed to be

Comment: Where do you get that format of Date?

Comment: Maybe this answer will help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/25817039/2724332

Comment: @PanosAngel Note that in the same post you reference, another poster found some errors and improved the algorithm: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34059193/5961578. But the OP's timestamp appears to be milliseconds since Year 0/1 instead of milliseconds since Unix epoch.

Comment: My mistake: The timestamp includes a negative number, and it does represent milliseconds from epoch. Parsing using the method provided by @algofoogle at http://stackoverflow.com/a/34059193/5961578, the OP's timestamp parses to `0001-01-01 00:00:00 -0500`.

Comment: @moveson & Panos Angel, you guys are right. This date I think is some kind of a null being returned from the server. The conversion method works fine. Thank you for your help